# Python & Arduino communication - TypeError: must be real number, not str

Tags: python, arduino, k-means

I want to use the kmeans1d library to cluster some values from an Arduino, however, I got a TypeError from Python.

Below is the Arduino code:

```cpp
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("100, 150, 300, 130, 140");
  delay(5000);
}
```

Python code:

```py
import kmeans1d
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
r1=ser.readline()
#x = [100, 110, 130, 103, 102]
x = [r1.decode('utf-8')]
k = 2
clusters, centroids = kmeans1d.cluster(x, k)
print(clusters)   # [1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: You should add the error you got and Python code used alongside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a string where a number is expected.

Try something like this:

```py
x = r1.decode('utf8').rstrip().split(", ")
for i in range(0, len(x)): 
    x[i] = int(x[i])
```

Comment: still not work....shown another Error.    x = r1.rstrip().split(", ")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: x = r1.split(", ") still not work...shown same error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: x = r1.decode('utf8').rstrip().split(", ") It really works!!!!!thx a lot ......Next step, i need to think how to keep loop clustering, as the valve will keep change...any hints for me? i'm tring while True

Comment: Which one works, the top one or the bottom one? Don't forget to vote and accept the answer. My Python is a bit rusty, as you have noticed; I don't know the best way forward for your loop. Just experiment 8-). Does it have to run forever?

Comment: while True: will run forever; try it. You could have the Arduino send a special string like "STOP" and do: if (r1.decode('utf8').rstrip() == "STOP") break or something like that if you want the loop to stop.